# File Upload using JQuery Ajax with Struts1

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, struts-1

My requirement is to submit a HTML form (Including File Type and Text Type) using AJAX call, I am using Struts-1 at the server side to parse the http request. Below is the code i have wrote, but its giving me  exception when i try to print the name of the file.

JavaScript Code :-

```
function saveUpdateRfc(formId) {

    console.log("Enter in Upload Script");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file",formId.files[0]);
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url : "AddRfc.do",
        type : "POST",
        data : formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success : function(result) {
            if (result.result == "success") {
                console.log("Rfc Added");
            } else {
                bootbox
                    .alert("Some Error Occured While Opening this Rfc. Please refresh the page and try again.If this Problem Persists, please report it to dev team.");
            }
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
        console.log(thrownError);
        bootbox
            .alert("Some Error Occured While Opening this Rfc. Please refresh the page and try again.If this Problem Persists, please report it to dev team.");
        },
        complete : function() {
        }
    });
}
```

At Server Side, Here is the java code to get the file from the form.

```
        RfcLogBean log = new RfcLogBean();
        log = (RfcLogBean) form;

        FormFile uploadedTakeoffSheet = log.getMyFile();

        System.out.println("======= " +uploadedTakeoffSheet.getFileName());
        System.out.println("======= " +uploadedTakeoffSheet.getContentType());
```

Can someone please help.!!

Comment: It gives me null pointer exception.

Comment: So `uploadedTakeoffSheet` is null? What's `RfcLogBean`? Why do you create a new one only to immediately throw it away an reassign it to a cast-ed `form`? What's the point of the multipart request wrapper if you think you already have the file? Etc.

Comment: Yes "uploadedTakeoffSheet" is null. RFCLogBean is my POJO (ActionForm) which is bind to the HTML Form.

Comment: I was trying by using Multipart Wrapper,i removed it from the code now.

Comment: You've verified the file is being sent correctly by examining the request in either the browser console or a proxy?

Comment: Yeah, I dont see the file in request in my browser console.